# How to check if there is an active MySQLi connection in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I have extended my Database Models from the `mysqli` class, but i don't want it to reconnect everytime i instantiate a new model, because it really slows down the whole script.

I have a `Database` class extends from `mysqli`, and other *model classes* extending from `Database`.

My `Database` class looks like this :

```
class Database extends mysqli {

    // some properties ...

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(MySQL_HOST, MySQL_USER, MySQL_PASS, MySQL_DATABASE);
        $this->set_charset(MySQL_CHARACTER_SET);

        // initializing stuff ..             
    }

    // some other methods...     
}
```

A sample model class would look like this :

```
class User extends Database {
    protected $table = "users";

public function __construct($id = null) {
    // Calling the parent constructor.
    parent::__construct();
    if($id) {
        // This is the current logged-in user.
        // Importing all session data into this object.
        $this->data->import($this->session->all());
        // ^^ This imports all the user related session data into this object 
        // i don't think it's relevant but i'll leave it here just in case.
    }                
}
```

My question is,

- How can i check if there is an active `mysqli` connection?
- How can i prevent it from reconnecting and use the active connection instead?
- What other approaches can i follow?
- Should i migrate to `PDO`, do i have to? *Why?*

*P.S.: Migrating to PDO will be a lot of rework, as i've already built things over mysqli.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **How can i check if there is an active** `mysqli` **connection?**

You can use `mysqli::ping()` method to check if the connection is alive.

This is from [php.net](http://php.net/mysqli_ping#example-1677) :

```
if ($mysqli->ping()) {
    printf ("Our connection is ok!\n");
} else {
    printf ("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

- **How can i prevent it from reconnecting and use the active connection instead?**

As the other answers say, using a persistent connection will solve your problem. Add `p:` prefix to your host name.

```
parent::__construct("p:" . MySQL_HOST, MySQL_USER, MySQL_PASS, MySQL_DATABASE);
```

- **What other approaches can i follow?**

You could consider using PDO instead, but if you don't need to support other DB types, or prepared statements mysqli looks more lightweight to me.

Answer (score 1):

When connecting to the database you can put p: before the hostname to initiate a persistent connection. Like, `p:mysite.com` or `p:localhost`. This may help with speed (if you are not already doing it)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
parent::__construct("p:".$host, MySQL_USER, MySQL_PASS, MySQL_DATABASE);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but i'm not using the procedural approach. This is also what @SyntaxLAMP has suggested. Works fine, but not enough for my question. Thank you.