# How can I set up a mysqli object without actually connecting yet?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have several classes for differents objects that all share the same database. I'd like these objects to share the same MySQLi connection, so I don't have to have a connection for every object, but not all commands require an active MySQLi connection, so I'd like to set that up when I need it. Connecting to the MySQL server every time the API is called is a huge waste of resources in my case.

So my main API would have something like this (idealy):

```
$db = new mysqli();
$a = new objA( $db );

class objA{
    private $db;

    function __construct( $db ){
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    function doSomething(){
        if( !$this->db->isConnected() )
            $this->db->connect( MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS );

        return $this->db->query( MY_QUERY );
    }
}
```

So, the database connection would only be build if I would call `$a->doSomething()` from the API. This setup would also enable me to use the same MySQL connection in a completely different object.

How can I get a function like `$mysql->isConnected()` to check if the actual connection to the MySQL database is built and to build it if it hasn't?

Comment: Have you tried using a Singleton for your database connection?

Comment: that's not the issue... I'm not trying to force only one connection, I'm trying to prevent communicating with the MySQL server until I really need to.

Comment: Do you have to define the `$db = new mysqli();`? Is it possible for you to just assign `null` to it and validate `if ($this->db === null)` then there is no connection and your assign your `$this->db = new mysqli();` before you connect in the if statement.

Comment: this would be an option 'til I realized I'm sharing the same connection between different objects. So I'd match rather define an 'empty' mysql object that I can share between objects, but that only actually connects to the database server when I need the connection

Comment: Have you looked at this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676155/how-to-check-if-there-is-an-active-mysqli-connection-in-php

Comment: I checked the link, it has an answer to build a persistent link, which is the same problem... the link did however have a clue about $db->ping. If I set up the mysql object with no params ($db=new mysqli()) $db->ping() will cause a (suppressible) error. After connecting it does work! It's nasty, but db->isConnected could be: return @$this->mysql->ping();

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the `ping()` part of the thread and I can't believe there isn't a clearer way to do it than using an error. I'll keep looking later tonight.

Comment: Thanks. Problem with this ping method is that for every actual query there's a ping first, doubling the amount of queries. A 'dummy class' around mysqli might be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deriving a class from mysqli called lazyMysqli:

```
class lazyMysqli extends mysqli{
    private $init;

    private $mysql_host;
    private $mysql_username;
    private $mysql_passwd;
    private $mysql_dbname;
    private $mysql_port;
    private $mysql_socket;

    function __construct( $host = null, $username = null, $passwd = null, 
        $dbname = null, $port = null, $socket = null ){
        $this->mysql_host = $host;
        $this->mysql_username = $username;
        $this->mysql_passwd = $passwd;
        $this->mysql_dbname = $dbname;
        $this->mysql_port = $port;
        $this->mysql_socket = $socket;

        $this->init = false;
    }

    function init(){
        if( !$this->init ){
            parent::__construct( $this->mysql_host, $this->mysql_username, 
                $this->mysql_passwd, $this->mysql_dbname, 
                $this->mysql_port, $this->mysql_socket );
            $this->init = true;
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

now, instead of defining a new `mysqli` I use a `lazyMysqli`:

```
$db = new lazyMysqli( MYSQLHOST, MYSQLUSER, MYSQLPASS );
```

this will initialize everything and the object can be passed to other classes for instance. Before every live action to the database I call `lazyMysqli::init()` to actually set up the connection to the server. This way I don't have to waste resources and not having to actually build a connection to the server before I need it, and I'm still able to share the mysqli object with other classes.

the `init()` function returns the object itself, so it can be bubbled:

```
$db->init()->query(...)
```